# Modify IntelliJ custom properties in plugin tests

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I develop plugin for IntelliJ. How can I modify [custom properties](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tuning-the-ide.html#configure-platform-properties) for my plugin tests?

For example I want to set `idea.max.content.load.filesize` property to, say, `100MiB`

Answer (score 0):

These are system properties, so java.lang.System#setProperty

Comment: But it will not work if property is accessed before I call `setProperty`? For example `idea.max.content.load.filesize` property [is saved in global static final variable](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/util-rt/src/com/intellij/openapi/util/io/FileUtilRt.java#L31)

Comment: Then you'll have to add corresponding system properties to your test runner

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the properties you wish to modify, you may be able to use **idea.properties**, which contains the "*default properties used to run IntelliJ IDEA*" (per the link you provided). To modify the file, you go to **Help** > **Edit Custom Properties...** (see [these](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207240985-Changing-IDE-default-directories-used-for-config-plugins-and-caches-storage) [steps](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#change-ide-dirs)).

For example, I used this approach to address a problem where my machine's security software was blocking plugins that used IntelliJ's [default](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs) [config](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#config-directory) directory (*C:\Users<user>\AppData...*).

This is the Windows OS default Application Data directory and is included in the paths scanned by the security software. By moving my **idea.properties** file to a different directory (*c:/development/idea/caches/*), not automatically scanned by the security software, my plugins were no longer blocked.

It's a different use case from what you're describing, but may be an approach worth looking into.